# Incomplete last vertical line in table with an image

Tags: tables

I want to make a table in LaTeX and I wrote the following program:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{multirow}



\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c||c|c|c|c}
\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{}}& $\gamma_n$ & $\rho_{00}^\infty$  +     $\eta_{\infty}$ & $\rho_{00}^\infty$  + $\eta_{\infty}$ & $\gamma_n$ &     \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{1}{*}{}}\\
\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{\includegraphics[height=20mm]{fnodiss.eps}}& 0.01 & 0.2&     0.01 & 0.2 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{5}{*}{\includegraphics[height=20mm]{fnodiss.eps}}}   \\
\cline{2-5}‬ 
& 0.01 & 0.2 & 0.01 & 0.2   \\
\cline{2-5}‬
 & 0.01 & 0.2& 0.01 & 0.2  \\
\cline{2-5}‬
& 0.01 & 0.2& 0.01 & 0.2  \\
\cline{2-5}‬
& \textcolor{red}{0.9399} & 0.2 & 0.01 & 0.2 \\
\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{\includegraphics[height=20mm]{fnodiss.eps}}& 0.01 & 0.2 & 0.01 & 0.2  &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{5}{*}{33O}}  \\
\cline{2-5}‬ 
& 0.01 & 0.2& 0.01 & 0.2  \\
\cline{2-5}‬
& 0.01 & 0.2& 0.01 & 0.2  \\
\cline{2-5}‬
& 0.01 & 0.2& 0.01 & 0.2  \\
\cline{2-5}‬
& 0.01 & 0.2 & 0.01 & 0.2 \\
\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{\includegraphics[height=20mm]{fnodiss.eps}}& 0.01 & 0.2 &     0.01 & 0.2  &\multirow{5}{*}{\includegraphics[height=20mm]{fnodiss.eps}}      \\
\cline{2-5}‬ 
& 0.01 & 0.2 & 0.01 & 0.2 \\
\cline{2-5}‬
& 0.01 & 0.2 & 0.01 & 0.2 \\
\cline{2-5}‬
& 0.01 & 0.2 & 0.01 & 0.2 \\
\cline{2-5}‬
& 0.01 & 0.2 & 0.01 & 0.2 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

and it works good except the last column is not perfect, mean the last vertical line is not complete.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot ampersands at the end of some rows. I took the opportunity to improve your table, with the `hhline` package, and made some corrections and simplifications to the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, multirow, hhline}
\newcommand\myhline{\hhline{~|--||--~}}

\begin{document}

\centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c||c|c|c|c|}
\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& $γ_n$ & $ρ_{00}^∞$ + $η_{∞}$ & $ρ_{00}^∞$ + $η_{∞}$ & $γ_n$ & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\[2pt]
\hhline{---||---}
\multirow{5}{*}[-0.6ex]{\includegraphics[height=20mm, width=35mm]{fnodiss.eps}}& 0.01 & 0.2& 0.01 & 0.2 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{5}{*}[-0.6ex]{\includegraphics[height=20mm, width=35mm]{fnodiss.eps}}} \\
\myhline%
& 0.01 & 0.2 & 0.01 & 0.2 & \\
\myhline
‬ & 0.01 & 0.2& 0.01 & 0.2 & \\
\myhline
& 0.01 & 0.2& 0.01 & 0.2 & \\
\myhline
& \textcolor{red}{0.9399} & 0.2 & 0.01 & 0.2 & \\
\hhline{---||---}
\multirow{5}{*}[-0.6ex]{\includegraphics[height=20mm, width=35mm]{fnodiss.eps}}& 0.01 & 0.2 & 0.01 & 0.2 &\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{5}{*}{33O}} \\
\myhline
& 0.01 & 0.2& 0.01 & 0.2 & \\
\myhline
& 0.01 & 0.2& 0.01 & 0.2 & \\
\myhline
& 0.01 & 0.2& 0.01 & 0.2 & \\
\myhline
& 0.01 & 0.2 & 0.01 & 0.2 & \\
\hhline{---||---}
\multirow{5}{*}[-0.6ex]{\includegraphics[height=20mm, width=35mm]{fnodiss.eps}}& 0.01 & 0.2 & 0.01 & 0.2 &\multirow{5}{*}[-0.6ex]{\includegraphics[height=20mm, width=35mm]{fnodiss.eps}} \\
\myhline
& 0.01 & 0.2 & 0.01 & 0.2 & \\
\myhline
& 0.01 & 0.2 & 0.01 & 0.2 & \\
\myhline
& 0.01 & 0.2 & 0.01 & 0.2 & \\
\myhline
& 0.01 & 0.2 & 0.01 & 0.2 & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I little rearrange your example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c||c|c|c|c|}
\cline{2-5}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{1}{*}{}}
    &   $\gamma_n$ & $\rho_{00}^\infty$  +  $\eta_{\infty}$
        &   $\rho_{00}^\infty$  + $\eta_{\infty}$
            &   $\gamma_n$
                &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{}    \\
\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{\includegraphics[height=20mm]{example-image}}
    &   0.01
        & 0.2
            &   0.01
                &   0.2
                    &                   \\
\cline{2-5}‬
    & 0.01  & 0.2   & 0.01 & 0.2    &   \\
\cline{2-5}‬
    & 0.01  & 0.2   & 0.01 & 0.2    &   \\
\cline{2-5}‬
    & 0.01  & 0.2   & 0.01 & 0.2    &   \\
\cline{2-5}‬
    & \textcolor{red}{0.9399} 
            & 0.2   & 0.01 & 0.2    &
                        \multirow{-5}{*}{\includegraphics[height=20mm]{example-image}}   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

and last line is appear:
[image]